# HTML Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, .net, html, visual-studio-2008, nullreferenceexception

I have a simple web page. Its contents:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" 
         AutoEventWireup="true" 
         CodeFile="default.aspx.cs" 
         Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC 
          "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" 
        content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" 
        runat="server">
    <div id="header" >
      <asp:Button
           ID="previous_BUT"
           runat="server"
           Height="25px"
           Text="Previous" 
           Visible="false"
           Width="100px" />
      <asp:Label
           ID="txtNewsItem"
           runat="server"
           Height="20px"  
           Visible="false"
           Width="550px" />
      <asp:Button
           ID="next_BUT"
           runat="server"
           Height="25px"
           Text="Next" 
           Visible="false"
           Width="100px" />
    </div>

  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The code behind page (excluding Session variable and Web.config value retrievals) is

```
using ...

// **************************************************** class _Default

public partial class _Default : Page
    {

    DataTable   news_items = null;

    // ********************************************* Connection_String

    /// <summary>
    /// get the value of the database connection string from 
    /// the Web.Config file ConnectionString element
    /// </summary>
    public string Connection_String ...

    // ********************************************* Current_News_Item

    /// <summary>
    /// set or get the value of the Current_News_Item Session
    /// variable
    /// </summary>
    private int Current_News_Item ...

    // ********************************************* Number_News_Items

    /// <summary>
    /// set or get the value of the Number_News_Items Session 
    /// variable
    /// </summary>
    private int Number_News_Items ...

    // ************************************************ get_news_items

    /// <summary>
    /// retrieve the news items from the database
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private DataTable get_news_items ( )
        {
        DataTable       data_table = null;
        SqlConnection   SQL_connection = null;

        try
            {
            DataSet         data_set = new DataSet ( );
            DateTime        now = DateTime.Now;
            StringBuilder   select_statement;
            SqlDataAdapter  SQL_data_adapter;
            DateTime        today;

            today = new DateTime ( now.Year, now.Month, now.Day );

            select_statement = new StringBuilder ( ).AppendFormat (
                "SELECT hpn.description " +
                "FROM tbl_homePageNews hpn " +
                "WHERE effectiveDate <= GETDATE() and status = 1 " +
                "ORDER BY sortOrder ASC",
                today.ToShortDateString ( ) );

            SQL_connection = new SqlConnection ( Connection_String );
            SQL_connection.Open ( );

            SQL_data_adapter = new SqlDataAdapter ( 
                                       select_statement.ToString ( ),
                                       SQL_connection );
            SQL_data_adapter.Fill ( data_set, "tbl_homePageNews" );

            data_table = data_set.Tables [ "tbl_homePageNews" ].
                                  Copy ( );
            }
        catch
            {
            data_table = null;
            }
        finally
            {
            if ( SQL_connection != null )
                {
                SQL_connection.Close ( );
                }
            }

        return ( data_table );
        }

    // ***************************************************** Page_Load

    protected void Page_Load ( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {

        next_BUT.Click += new EventHandler( next_BUT_Click );
        previous_BUT.Click += new EventHandler( previous_BUT_Click );

        Current_News_Item = 0;
        Number_News_Items = 0;

        if ( !Page.IsPostBack )
            {
            news_items = get_news_items ( );

            if ( news_items != null )
                {
                Number_News_Items = news_items.Rows.Count;

                previous_BUT.Visible = false;
                txtNewsItem.Visible = false;
                next_BUT.Visible = false;

                if ( Number_News_Items > 0 )
                    {
                    txtNewsItem.Visible = true;
                    txtNewsItem.Text = 
                        "  " + 
                        news_items.Rows [ Current_News_Item ] 
                                        [ "description" ].
                                   ToString ( );

                    if ( Number_News_Items > 1 )
                        {
                        previous_BUT.Visible = true;
                        next_BUT.Visible = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    // ******************************************** previous_BUT_Click

    /// <summary>
    /// handle the Previous button click
    /// </summary>
    public void previous_BUT_Click ( Object sender,
                                     EventArgs e )
        {

        Current_News_Item--;
        if ( Current_News_Item < 0 )
            {
            Current_News_Item = Number_News_Items - 1;
            }

        txtNewsItem.Text =  
            "  " + news_items.Rows [ Current_News_Item ] 
                                   [ "description" ].ToString ( );
        }

    // ************************************************ next_BUT_Click

    /// <summary>
    /// handle the Next button click
    /// </summary>
    public void next_BUT_Click ( Object    sender,
                                 EventArgs e )
        {

        Current_News_Item++;
        if ( Current_News_Item >= Number_News_Items )
            {
            Current_News_Item = 0;
            }

        txtNewsItem.Text = 
            "  " + news_items.Rows [ Current_News_Item ] 
                                   [ "description" ].ToString ( );
        }

    } // class _Default
```

In the code behind, in Page_Load, are the statements

```
                    txtNewsItem.Visible = true;
                    txtNewsItem.Text = 
                        "  " + 
                        news_items.Rows [ Current_News_Item ] 
                                        [ "description" ].
                                   ToString ( );
```

Both execute as expected - the first news item is displayed. The user may click on the "Previous" button or "Next" button to move though the news items. But here the problem arises. The following code is where things go badly

```
    // ************************************************ next_BUT_Click

    /// <summary>
    /// handle the Next button click
    /// </summary>
    public void next_BUT_Click ( Object    sender,
                                 EventArgs e )
        {

        Current_News_Item++;
        if ( Current_News_Item >= Number_News_Items )
            {
            Current_News_Item = 0;
            }

        txtNewsItem.Text = 
            "  " + news_items.Rows [ Current_News_Item ] 
                                   [ "description" ].ToString ( );
        }
```

The statement

```
        txtNewsItem.Text = 
            "  " + news_items.Rows [ Current_News_Item ] 
                                   [ "description" ].ToString ( );
```

causes the error with txtNewsItem in red. The same error occurs in previous_BUT_Click.

Because the same statement is used in Page_Load, I cannot fathom the reason for the error.

Comment: @Henk the code is posted to the original post. TIA.

Comment: You're only loading your data the first time. Two answers below are on the spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code that you posted we can see that

```
 news_items = get_news_items ( );
```

Is only called the first time the page is loaded.

Add this line to your events and it will work.

---

I believe the problem is with news_items.  Please post the code where you declare that and the full code for page load.  Are you using `if (!isPostBack)`?

I believe you are and in the `if (!IsPostBack)` you are loading the new_items table.

Comment: That was it. I also moved the initialization of Current_News_Item and Number_News_Items within the if ( !Page.IsPostBack ) guard.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the code that fills your `news_items` collection is only executed on initial `Page_Load` invocation (that is when `Page.IsPostBack == false`)?

Comment: That is correct. But now that I'm looking at it, maybe Current_News_Item, Number_News_Item, and the event handler declarations should all be guarded by if ( !Page.IsPostBack ).

Comment: Button's Click event handler is only invoked when there is a postback, so you shouldn't add there !Page.IsPostBack guard. I would rather suggest filling news_items on each Page_Load (maybe from some cached source if getting those news is time consuming).

Answer (score 0):

Check if `news_items.Rows[Current_News_Item + 1]["description"].ToString();` in onLoad would cause the same exception - if yes, then other items except for the default one haven't been initialized, or their descriptions haven't been initialized.

Comment: when the page loads, the first news item from the DB appears. It's when I click on next or previous that I encounter difficulties. TIA